# PHP function parameter with callable hint... can it be NULL?

Tags: php, default-value, type-hinting

I would like to have a PHP function which accepts a parameter `A`, which I have given the type hint `callable`. Trouble is in some situations I would like to be able to pass `NULL` or something like that, as the parameter value, indicating that the call back hasn't been provided. I get the following error:

```
"Argument must be callable, NULL given".
```

Any ideas how I can implement this please?

In response to answers posted and questions...

PHP version is 5.4.14

Code is...

```
class DB
{
    protected function ExecuteReal($sqlStr, array $replacements, callable $userFunc, $allowSensitiveKeyword)
    {
        ...
        if( $userFunc != NULL && is_callable($userFunc) )
            $returnResult = $call_user_func($userFunc, $currRow);
        ...
    }

    ...
    public function DoSomething(...)
    {
        $result = $this->ExecuteReal($queryStr, Array(), NULL, TRUE);   
        ...
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, I don't need to be called back with any data so instead of passing in a callable object I just pass in NULL. But this is the cause of the error msg.

The solution is answer below... thanks guys :)

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Yes, what have you done so far? What invokes this error message?

Comment: Witch PHP version you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use type-hinting (only `array` `interface`s, and `class`es can be type-hinted /till php 5.6/. /since 7.0 it is possible to typehint scalar types as well/), you can set the default value of the parameter to null. If you want to, let the parameter be optional.

```
$something = 'is_numeric';
$nothing = null;

function myFunction(Callable $c = null){
      //do whatever

}
```

All works:

```
 myFunction();
 myFunction($nothing);
 myFunction($something);
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot `callable` was introduced in 5.4, so my remark is invalid (dos not work when passing string)

Comment: @Kovge & dev-null-dweller... Thanks guys. Think that answers my question. Is there any way of doing this without having to give it a default value?

Answer (score -1):

You can only type hint objects and arrays. Typehinted variables can be null if the function is declared like this:

`function aFn($required, MyCallable $optional=null){ /*do stuff */}`

where `MyCallable` is a class name or the keyword `Array`.

Comment: I think this is now out of date - you can use `callable` as a hint, since 5.4.